# How to get value of a macro immediately

Tags: tex-core

The following code does not work. I think maybe it is because of `\f`.

So my question is: how to get the value from a macro immediately(in my case I want `\f` get `abc` immediately)? And is it possible to define the macro `\f` by `\edef`?

I tried `\edef\f{\ifthenelse{\equal{a}{a}}{abc}{def}}` and failed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen,xstring}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\f{\ifthenelse{\equal{a}{a}}{abc}{def}}
\def\g{abc}
\IfStrEq{\f}{\g}{Yes}{No}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is expandability, `\ifthenelse` isn't expandable. To compare two strings with expanding them before comparison you can use `\str_if_eq:eeTF` from `expl3`. Note that string comparison doesn't consider category codes, so the following isn't entirely equal to your `\ifthenelse` implementation (that would consider category codes).

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \myifstreq \str_if_eq:eeTF
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\newcommand*\f{\myifstreq{a}{a}{abc}{def}}
\newcommand*\g{abc}
\myifstreq{\f}{\g}{Yes}{No}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I know if a macro is expandability?

Comment: @lyl in the case of macros defined in `expl3`, you can take a look at `texdoc interface3`, every expandable macro is marked with a red star next to its name in that reference. Else a simple rule of thumb is: If it needs any assignments it can't be expandable. If it is defined as a "robust" or "protected" macro, it isn't expandable. If it uses optional arguments it most likely isn't expandable (there are a few mechanisms to expandably get optional arguments, but those are used relatively rare). Best you search for a good explanation (and if you don't find any, ask a question).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are using non-expandable LaTeX macros instead directly TeX primitives. The `\if...` primitives are expandable:

```
\def\f{\ifx aaabc\else def\fi}  % instead \newcommand\f{\ifthenelse{\equal{a}{a}}{abc}{de
\def\g{abc}
\edef\test{\f} % the current (expandable) value of \f in in \test
\ifx\g\test Yes\else No\fi % instead \IfStrEq{\f}{\g}{Yes}{No}
\bye
```

The `\if...` commands are described in [TeX in the Nutshell](http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/tex-nutshell.pdf#cs:if), for example.

Comment: Many thanks for your solution. In my example, charactor `a` is used for comparation. How to compare strings by Tex primitives? It seems that `\ifx aaaa` is no not a correct way.

Comment: TeX does not use strings but only tokens or tokens lists. You cannot compare what does not exists in TeX. But extensions of TeX (pdfTeX or XeTeX) have `\pdfstrcmp` primitive which converts two token lists to strings, does comparison and returns -1, 0 +1. This result can be compared by `\ifnum`. All these primitives are expandable. LuaTeX can compare strings at Lua level, `\directlua` is expandable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using `\IfStrEq` which is meant to compare strings, and for `\ifthenelse` to do its magic, it doesn't really evaluate to a string. As you noticed, `\edef` doesn't help in this context.

What you need to do, is to modify your command to define a macro with the desired result, e.g.,

```
\newcommand\f{\ifthenelse{\equal{a}{a}}{\def\foo{abc}}{\def\foo{def}}}
```

(if you're not concerned about `\f` being reusable, you could use `\def\f` instead of `\def\foo` at that point. Then your call to `\IfStrEq` evaluates as expected.

Comment: Would you please say more about why my version of `\newcommmand\f" can not give the value of `abc` to `\f` ? And why is it impossible to design the macro `\f` by `edef`?